# How to process xml file having same node in .net

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have a  xml file out of which i am posting a part as shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bulkCmConfigDataFile>
  <fileHeader/>
  <configData>
    <class name="FPE">
      <object technique="FPE" vendor="test" version="123">
        <class name="eNodeBCell_eNodeB">
          <object>
            <parameter name="LocalCellId" value="0"/>
          </object>
        </class>
        <class name="eNodeB_eNodeB">
          <object>
            <parameter name="eNodeBId" value="64946"/>
          </object>
        </class>
      </object>
    </class>
  </configData>
</bulkCmConfigDataFile>
```

i have two `string` variables in c# like `localCellId` and `enodebId`so i want to get `localCellId` value as 0 and `enodebId` value as 64946.How to get it in c#
I tried in this way,but no results

```
    XElement main = XElement.Load(path);

    var results = main.Descendants("eNodeBCell_eNodeB")
        .Descendants("parameter")
        .Where(e => e.Value == "LocalCellId")
        .Select(e => new { localcellid = e.Descendants("LocalCellId").FirstOrDefault().Value});
```

Comment: `LocalCellId` and `eNodeBId` are at the same level. Still not clear what part of xml you want.

Comment: i need value of LocalCellId and eNodeBId from xml file which is like 0 and 64946

Comment: Can you give at least 2 **test cases** (pairs of input and output)?

Comment: string localCellId =value of LocalCellId from xml file which is 0 and string enodebId  = value of enodebId from xml file which is 64946

Comment: Theses are completely two parallel nodes with almost no relationship. Why are you always talking them together?

Comment: @LeiYang I think it's something comparable to `FPE : { eNodeBCell_eNodeB : { LocalCellId : 0 }, eNodeB_eNodeB : { eNodeBId : 64946 } , technique: "FPE", vendor : "test", version : "123" }`.. so there is a sensible relationship here.

Comment: @peter .. XPath is an appropriate way to handle this, but you could use XSLT (which uses XPath and XQuery) to define another XML document with reference to a schema (.xsd) then deserialize that into an object.

Comment: of course, you can do that process in memory

Comment: Try this :             var results = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Attribute("name") != null && x.Attribute("value") != null).Select(x => new {
                name = (string)x.Attribute("name"),
                value = (int)x.Attribute("value")
        }).ToList();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your LINQ to XML attempt, I think the XPath that you are looking for is something like this:

```
var xDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load("1.xml");
string localcellid = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("//*[@*='eNodeBCell_eNodeB']//parameter[@*='LocalCellId']/@value").Value;
string eNodeBId = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("//*[@*='eNodeB_eNodeB']//parameter[@*='eNodeBId']/@value").Value;
```

You can replace `[@*='` with `[@name='` (I tested both) and add more specific information to the XPath.

---

For comparison, a LINQ to XML version:

```
var main = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load("1.xml");

string localcellid = main.Descendants()
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Attributes().Any(a => a.Value == "eNodeBCell_eNodeB"))
    .Descendants("parameter")
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Attributes().Any(a => a.Value == "LocalCellId"))
    .Attribute("value").Value;

string eNodeBId = main.Descendants()
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Attributes().Any(a => a.Value == "eNodeB_eNodeB"))
    .Descendants("parameter")
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Attributes().Any(a => a.Value == "eNodeBId"))
    .Attribute("value").Value;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the `value` attribute of those two elements then you could use XPath expressions.

```
var xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<bulkCmConfigDataFile>
  <fileHeader/>
  <configData>
    <class name=""FPE"">
      <object technique=""FPE"" vendor=""test"" version=""123"">
        <class name=""eNodeBCell_eNodeB"">
          <object>
            <parameter name=""LocalCellId"" value=""0""/>
          </object>
        </class>
        <class name=""eNodeB_eNodeB"">
          <object>
            <parameter name=""eNodeBId"" value=""64946""/>
          </object>
        </class>
      </object>
    </class>
  </configData>
</bulkCmConfigDataFile>";

var document = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var localCellId = document.XPathSelectElement("//parameter[@name='LocalCellId']").Attribute("value").Value as string;
var eNodeBId = document.XPathSelectElement("//parameter[@name='eNodeBId']").Attribute("value").Value as string;

Console.WriteLine("LocalCellId: {0}", localCellId);
Console.WriteLine("eNodeBId: {0}", eNodeBId);
```

Comment: He will end up telling you this is not what he wants. I bet.

Comment: Yeah, I know. It's probably a twenty-line snippet of a 20,000 line XML file. Seeing that classes can have objects, which can have classes, which can have objects, which then have parameters, kinda gives me a weird feeling.